# Powerful Laptop with dedicated graphics card

Tags: laptop, ubuntu

I hope you can help me.

I´m searching for a powerful laptop with following criteria:

- 16GB RAM
- 500GB SSD
- NVIDIA graphics card
- Ubuntu OS

It doesn´t matter if the laptop has less RAM or a smaller SSD ( i can upgrade these two components later).

The most important thing is that its NVIDIA graphics card works well with Ubuntu.

It will be used for software development with OpenGL on Ubuntu. It would be great if the dedicated graphics card can be set for primary usage.

What kind of laptop would be appropriate for our use?

Comment: Does the laptop need to come with Ubuntu preinstalled or are you able to do that yourself?

Comment: What's your budget and why does it need to be a laptop as opposed to a desktop computer? I ask because the answer to that question usually helps people select a better laptop for your purposes.

Comment: If you're looking for gaming performance, you'll get much better results out of a desktop graphics card as opposed to a mobile/laptop graphics card.

Comment: @ArtOfCode he says he needs it for OpenGL software development for whatever that's worth.

Comment: You'll still get much better performance out of a desktop card :) Honestly, unless you *absolutely need* to be developing, with that much power, on the go, you should look at getting a powerful desktop, and a smaller laptop that can just tide you over until you get back to the desk.

Answer (score 3):

I am currently running an Oryx Pro from [System76](https://system76.com/) and it is serving me very well, I've configured it with:

- 24GB of DDR4
- A 250GB NVMe SSD (+ a 1TB hdd)
- A GTX 970M Graphics Card
- And an i7-6700HQ processor.
- (Everything working with 16.04 LTS)

Although this meets all your requirements, I spent $2000 on mine, you're probably going to [configure it differently.](https://system76.com/cart/configure/oryp2) (Now with GTX 10xx cards too!)

They come with Ubuntu installed by default, and I have absolutely loved my Oryx so far, hope you get an equally great experience if you choose to buy one. I have had zero issues with graphics drivers or video/x-server configuration. It just works as it should.